# How to merge two String variable

Tags: vba

I have

```
Dim FatherContent As String
Dim MotherContent As String
```

I'm new in VB and I want to ask how to merge 2 string variable and merge the common name and remove the non-common name.

Comment: give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't the clearest one I've seen today, but one method for what I believe you're asking is if you have a string: `John Doe` and `Jane Doe`, you want to keep the common name of `Doe`.

There are a few ways you can do it, but for simplicity we will use `Split()` and compare the array:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim FatherContent As String
    Dim MotherContent As String

    FatherContent = "John Doe"
    MotherContent = "Jane Doe"

    MsgBox getCommonName(FatherContent, MotherContent) '<-- Returns Doe

End Sub

Function getCommonName(ByVal name1 As String, ByVal name2 As String) As String

    Dim name1Arr() As String, name2Arr() As String
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, bFlag As Boolean

    'You should probably add some error handling to ensure the strings
    'passed contain a space so the split() function doesn't fail

    name1Arr = Split(name1)
    name2Arr = Split(name2)

    For i = 0 To UBound(name1Arr)
        For x = 0 To UBound(name2Arr)
            If name1Arr(i) = name2Arr(x) Then
                getCommonName = name1Arr(i)
                bFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        If bFlag = True Then Exit For
    Next i

End Function
```